# Python/Django - Build list by Sum by day and Week

Tags: python, django, dictionary, dayofweek

Hopefully I can explain what I am trying to accomplish. I have no problem achieving my result, but I know that this is probably not the best way to do it.

I have a table with some entries by date. I am trying to take those entries from the current month, and arrange them into a list by week, and then sum a value from the table for each day of the week. The end result would look something like this:

```
{44: {4: Decimal('2.80'), 5: Decimal('6.30')}, 45: {1: Decimal('8.90'), 2: Decimal('10.60')}}
```

I have a solution. But, I know this is not the best way to do it. Any ideas about how to make this better?

```
#Queries the database and returns time objects that have fields 'hours' and 'date'
time = self.month_time()

r = {}
for t in time:
    #Get the week of the year number
    week = t.date.isocalendar()[1]

    #Get the day of the week number
    day = t.date.isoweekday()

    if week not in r:
        r.update({week:{}})
    if day not in r[week]:
        r[week][day] = 0

    r[week][day] = r[week][day] + t.hours
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are probably looking for the [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).  A `defaultdict` is just like a dictionary, except when a KeyError would be thrown with `dict`, the factory function given upon initialization is used to create an initial value.

In your case, you'll need a `defaultdict` for `days` nested inside one for `weeks`.  I think this will work for you:

```
from collections import defaultdict

r = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
for t in time:
    week = t.date.isocalendar()[1]
    day = t.date.isoweekday()
    r[week][day] += t.hours
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out and let you know.